# Formulating a simple combinatorics problem in a 3x3 grid

Tags: combinatorics

I have a 3x3 grid, and I want to move from a point A in the left corner below, to a point B in the right corner above. I can move 2 times horizontally, and 2 times vertically. The number of paths that allow me to do this are 6 (the combinations of 4 in 2).
Now I would like to put the restriction of finding the paths that go from A to B WITHOUT passing through the central vertex of the grid. The result should be 2, but I know this because i did drawings. I would like to know how to formulate the problem algebraically, so that then i could be able to generalize it for an nxn grid.
I don't have a clue about how to do this...

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose more generally that we wish to move $a$ to the right, and $b$ up. We want to avoid a certain point $X$ which is $p$ to the right, and $q$ up.

Let us count the paths that go through $X$. There are $\binom{p+q}{p}\binom{a+b-p-q}{a-p}$ of these. For there are $\binom{p+q}{p}$ ways to go to $X$, and for **each** of these ways there are $\binom{a+b-p-q}{a-p}$ ways to go the rest of the way.

Subtract this number of bad paths from the total $\binom{a+b}{a}$.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to handle something like this is to note that if $P$ is the set of all such paths, $P_G$ ("$P$ Good") is the set that don't go through the center vertex, and $P_B$ ("$P$ Bad") is the set that DO go through the center vertex, then
$$
\lvert P_G\rvert=\lvert P\rvert-\lvert P_B\rvert.
$$
Can you see how to count the paths that go through the center vertex?  Note that choosing such a path consists of (1) choosing a path to the center vertex from the start and (2) choosing a path to the end from the center vertex.